# Как проверить значение в State? Python + Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state

участники форума. Хотелось бы выполнить проверку значения, что попадает в `State`, но никак не могу додуматься до реализации. Практиковаться в этом начал только сегодня. Пролистал интернет, но так ничего и не нашел.

#### Мой код

```
@dp.message_handler(state=reg.city, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def enterCity(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    print(f"{message.text} - MESSAGE TEXT")
    if message.text.lower() not in config.cities.lower():
        await message.reply("♦️ » Уточни свой город, пожалуйста:")
        return
    
    await state.update_data(city=message.text.title())
```

Мне требуется сделать правильное условие. Имеется список, где есть города. Я хочу проверить наличие элемента в списке через метод `str.lower()`

Нужно изменить это условие: `if message.text.lower() not in config.cities.lower():`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: [условие], state=reg.city)
def process_invalid(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer("Wrong.")
```

Это метод из официальной [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html)